# "Place Order" button on Magento onepage checkout isn't responding. (Inline JS not executing.)

Tags: javascript, magento

Currently trying to get onepage checkout working properly on an installation of Magento 1.6.0.0.

Each step works fine until the final review order box, the Place Order button gives the error `review not defined`, when trying to fire the `review.save()` OnClick event.

The following script should create this `review` object. It's in the same file as the button, and is called via AJAX when the user reaches the final step of the order process. If I access the file directly, this code is executed and the object created, it's only when it's pulled in by the checkout page that it doesn't run.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  review = new Review('http://example.org/checkout/onepage/saveOrder/', 'http://example.org/checkout/onepage/success/', $('checkout-agreements'));
  SageServer = new EbizmartsSagePaySuite.Checkout
  ({
     'checkout': checkout,
     'review': review,
     'payment': payment,
     'billing': billing,
     'accordion': accordion
  });
  //]]>
</script>
```

I can't seem to find anyone else who's encountered this problem, every version of this code (from various different modules) does it in this manner, so I'm not sure why this JS isn't being executed.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Already tried to use an uppercase 'R', i.e.`'review': Review,`?

Comment: I tried at the time, but this is definitely a case of the above script not being executed. If I add an alert to it it won't show up unless I view that bit of code directly. When it's being pulled in to the checkout page it won't show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this an upgrade? If so, try this: http://sree.cc/magento_ecommerce_tips/checkout-not-working-on-magento-version-1-4-x
Try even if it's not an upgrade. I fixed that exact same issue several times with this solution.

I would do a diff. with a software like WinMerge. Check the differences on your checkout design folders, and the base Magento one.

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout
vs.
app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/checkout

also check the XML file:
app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml
vs.
app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout/checkout.xml

Hope this helps.

Francois

Comment: Only just saw this over a year later! We found a workaround for the problem, however unfortunately I don't recall exactly what we did, but I believe the client simply requested we use a different checkout module and so the problem resolved itself. However I'm marking this as the answer because I'm almost certain this would have solved the problem, given the circumstances of the issue.

Answer (score 6):

We were migrating to a newer Magento version (1.8), and the "Place Order" button was not working for us as well.

Mukesh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517391/place-order-button-on-magento-onepage-checkout-isnt-responding-inline-js-no/25138012#25138012) pointed me to the right direction. However, the posted code was not working.

This worked for me:

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

Comment: This is what my problem was.  Thank you, David.

Comment: Spot on!
Thank you!!

Comment: This helped me after applying patch SUPEE 8788 v2 on a Magento 1.7 install. The key to this fix lies in this snippet `array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())`. You're obligated to use form keys after that patch.

Answer (score 3):

**In app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml, I replaced  & working grt.**

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('button') ?>
```

**with**

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="review.save();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Got solution of the same Issue by followwing code, May this will help you.

Replace the base file the following path
app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
(or)

Replace the line number 81 in info.phtml

review = new Review(’getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>’, ‘getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>’, $(’checkout-agreements’));